# Error when trying to download tweets from Twitter API to Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, twitter

I seem to be running into an error when attempting to download tweets into mongoose via the API. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm getting a "Error: Bad Twitter streaming request: 404" error.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
Twit = require('twit');
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/twittertesting';

const T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: '#',
    consumer_secret: '#',
    access_token: '#',
    access_token_secret: '#'
})

// connect to mongo via mongoose
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database connected");
});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
const userSchema = new Schema({}, {"strict": false});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;

const stream = T.stream('statuses/user_timeline', { user_id: 44196397 });

stream.on('tweet', function (obj) {

  const TwitterData = new User(obj); // create object
  TwitterData.save(); // save data to DB
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`const stream = T.stream('statuses/user_timeline')`

The `statuses/user_timeline` endpoint is not a streaming / realtime API, it is a REST endpoint. Assuming you want all the Tweets posted by a specific user - although this will also include replies and other Tweets to them - you would need to [use the `statuses/filter` Twitter endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter), with the parameter `follow: 44196397`.

Comment: We're trying to only get the tweets a specific user has posted. Not retweets or replies to them, etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: You’d have to filter those out out by checking if the event message types are Tweets or replies.